# Logging HTTPBody in Netfox and Moya

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, moya

I'm currently using [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) for my iOS project. I tried to use [Netfox](https://github.com/kasketis/netfox) to log my HTTP requests.

Since Moya is a wrapper of Alamofire, I ended up creating custom `Alamofire.SessionManager` with `NFXProtocol` in the `URLSessionConfiguration`'s `protocolClasses`. I successfully received the response log and headers for both request and response, but always missed the request body.

I stumbled upon [this fix on Netfox from 2015](https://github.com/kasketis/netfox/issues/16), but I got no idea how to use it with Moya. Do any of you know how to implement it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked this issue in Moya? https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues

Comment: @aldok I did, this issue is not listed yet there.

Answer (score 0):

Just use network logging plugin for Moya, it's part of Moya already, just need connect it. You can pass plugins array while you instantiating Moya provider:

```
let plugins = [NetworkLoggerPlugin()]
let provider = MoyaProvider<MyNetworkApiService>(manager: manager, plugins: plugins)
```

To enable logging only for development and disable for release build you can do next thing:

```
    var plugins: [PluginType] = []
    #if DEBUG
    plugins.append(NetworkLoggerPlugin())
    #endif
    let provider = MoyaProvider<MyNetworkApiService>(manager: manager, plugins: plugins)
```